# Google Apps Script - sheet.deleterow() deleting row and next row?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've got a problem with my google apps script in my spreadsheet - This code works very well however I've got a problem where sometimes it will delete the row and then the next row straight after? I've spent a few hours questioning this and it works when I execute the code by myself flawlessly but when I execute it from the spreadsheet it doesn't work?

The plan is when a user enters the value Y into a cell it means someone has completed and will copy the information from the in learning sheet into the completed sheet - when this code is triggered onedit, sometimes it will delete the row it should but then sometimes the row below - why is this and is there anyway to fix it?

```
function myOnEdit(e) {
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This function will run whenever a cell is edited
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Active sheet
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Get Active cell
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
var mycell = ss.getActiveSelection();
var cellcol = mycell.getColumn();
var cellrow = mycell.getRow();
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (sheet.getName() == "In Learning"){ // Check to see if the sheet is "In Learning"
if (cellcol == 19 && cellrow > 2){ // Check to see if the column is the learner complete column
  if (mycell.getValue() == "Y"){
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Completions"); // Get the Completions Sheet
    var targetrow = getFirstEmptyRow(targetSheet)+1; // Find the last row (prevents loads of empty rows horray)
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 1); // Copy the learner information
    sheet.getRange(cellrow, 1, 1, cellcol-1).moveTo(target); // Move the information   
    sheet.deleteRow(cellrow); // Delete it from in learning
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Learner has been completed', 'Completed', 3); // Alert the user
    sendEmail(learnerObjects, (cellrow-1));
    deleted = true;
  }
  else if (mycell.getValue() == "W"){ 
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Withdrawals"); // Get the withdrawals sheet
    var targetrow = getFirstEmptyRow(targetSheet)+1; // Find the last row
    sheet.getRange(cellrow, 1, 1, 4).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 1)); // Copy learner information and move it
    sheet.getRange(cellrow, 10, 1, 1).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 5)); // Copy learner information and move it
    sheet.getRange(cellrow, 6, 1, 2).moveTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 6)); // Copy learner information and move it
    sheet.deleteRow(cellrow); //Delete it from in learning
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Learner has been Withdrawn', 'Withdrawn', 3); // Alert the user
    deleted = true;
  }
  else {
    mycell.setValue("N");
  }
}
switch(cellcol){ // Otherwise check to see if the user is messing with formulas
  case 12: mycell.setFormula("=CONTINUE(L2, " + cellrow-1 + ", 1)");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Formula Corrected', 'Warning', 3);
    break;
  case 14: mycell.setFormula("=CONTINUE(N2, " + cellrow-1 + ", 1)");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Formula Corrected', 'Warning', 3);
    break;
  case 15: mycell.setFormula("=CONTINUE(O2, " + cellrow-1 + ", 1)");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Formula Corrected', 'Warning', 3);
    break;
}
if (deleted == false && sheet.getRange(cellrow,19).getValue() == "")
{
  sheet.getRange(cellrow,19).setValue("N");
}
}
if (sheet.getName() == "Completions"){
if (cellcol == 19 && cellrow > 1){ // Check to see if the column is the learner complete column
  if (mycell.getValue() == "Y"){
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("In Learning"); // Get the Completions Sheet
    var targetrow = getFirstEmptyRow(targetSheet)+1; // Find the last row (prevents loads of empty rows horray)
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetrow, 1); // Copy the learner information
    sheet.getRange(cellrow, 1, 1, cellcol-1).moveTo(target); // Move the information
    sheet.deleteRow(cellrow); // Delete it from in learning
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Learner completion has been revoked', 'Revoked Completion', 3); // Alert the user
    deleted = true;
  }
  else {
    mycell.setValue("N");
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe your code is indeed being executed twice when it's automatic. Put a `Browser.msgBox` to make sure.

Comment: That appears to be the case, I've just tested it there and a msgbox popped up twice. Is there any alternative methods?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, please try starting a new `onEdit` to test if it's running twice. Then make it more complex in small steps until you reach your current code. Always testing until you nail the problem. If you can come with a very simple code that anyone can copy and reproduce the problem it'll be much easier to help.

Comment: Its just in rare causes that it happens, I cant see anyway for this code to repeat.

Comment: You're out of luck. I guess you could try those usual IT solutions, like creating a new sheet and copying the data and code over to see if it stops. Or remove the trigger and set it with another user. Hum... think of that, maybe another user also set a trigger? But that would make it always run twice, not rarely like you're saying.

Comment: I've run into this before, where the editing done by the onEdit function triggers the onEdit function again. Recursion run amuck. Since scriptDb is dead, try creating a hidden sheet, then set a flag in the first cell like `firstcell.setValue('changed');`. On the first pass of your onEdit function, check for the presence of that flag. If it doesn't exist, run your function - then set the flag. If it DOES EXIST, don't run your function, and delete the flag - `setValue('');`

Comment: @rGil Just gave this a try and its still doing it, I think it could be the triggers - When i made this script I told every user of that spreadsheet they need the same trigger as myself for it to work - could this be a contributing to factor?

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu so if other users of the spreadsheet have the same trigger as myself it can cause that trigger to run twice? Will the trigger run even if i dont have that worksheet open? if yes - Then I think I have the solution that will fix my problem.

Comment: Yes, if more than one user have the installable trigger setup it will run multiple times. But that would not be a "rare" situation. It would run twice every time. E.g. send an email to you on every run to confirm. This way you can even see the account (on the from address) of who else setup the trigger.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu - That was the problem in the end. When I issued my guidance on how to use this I told everyone to make a trigger thinking that was how it worked. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: This question with such title and code, along with answers on comments will hardly ever benefit anyone else. I recommend you delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a similar issue with `onsubmit` when a form is submitted. It is a known Google problem where scripts sometimes run twice - I have seen it where the user logged in generating the event is different than the username that wrote the script. I found that the script ran as both users repeating the action I was trying to achieve.

My workaround was to check a cell in the sheet for a value that was set each time the script ran, so the script checks first if it already ran prior to running the code block taking action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
var mycell = e.source.getActiveSelection();
```

Comment: Nah, still deleting the two rows at times "/.

Comment: Can you verify the project triggers that are active for me?

Answer (score 0):

This was a weird one. Testing on simple scripts with combinations of function onEdit(e) don't fix it, such as:

```
function onEdit(e){ 
    var mycell = e.range // or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()
    e.source.deleteRow(mycell.getRow())// or SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(mycell.getRow())   
}
```

Instead, all variations appear to create two instances of .deleteRow() in succession, confirming as indicated in question. It's possible that the first iteration of onEdit that deletes the row, then that triggers a second instance of the onEdit on the row due to the delete(another changeType). changeType is not accessible because it is a simple trigger.

This is a work-around using PropertiesService that seemed to solve the problem for my use case:

```
function onEdit(e){

var delete_count = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("delete_count"); 

if (delete_count == null)  {
   e.source.deleteRow(e.range.getRow())//could call some other function here
   var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 
   properties.setProperty("delete_count", 1)   
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("delete_count")  
}
```

Essentially, works to block just one of the extra onEdit(e) -> .deleteRow() instances. Perhaps an installable rather than simple trigger might also work.